# Rails + Ransack - Drop Down List Collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I am loving the ransack gem for its flexibility, however I am unable to get the standard collection_select to function properly.  Perhaps someone can assist.

Example:

```
      <%= collection_select(:expense, :project_id, Project.all, 
        :id, :name, { prompt: 'Select Project'}, { class: 'span4' }) %>
```

in this case, this code is from an expense entry screen, so the first parameter is the expense object.  What should it be in the ransack form?  Also, I know I need to get the suffix in there.  In this example, I would like project_id_eq to be the search pattern.

Also, my form is on a controller and view called "reports", I am not putting this search in the default controllers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Seems that this will work.

```
<%= f.select :project_id_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Project.all, "id", "name", @search.project_id_eq) %>
```

If anyone has another suggestion, would love to know it too.

Comment: This works fairly well with the exception that it doesn't allow you to set a prompt ("Select").

Comment: @dspencer Just put the `include_blank: true` outside of the parentheses: `<%= f.select :languages_name_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Language.all, "id", "name"), include_blank: true %>`

Comment: can you please tell how to add eq  when we use option for select method and we are calling this from helper

Answer (score 24):

To do this with an include_blank, put it outside of the parentheses:

ex:

`<%= f.select :languages_id_eq, options_from_collection_for_select(Language.all, "id", "name"), include_blank: true %>`

== UPDATE ==

better yet, use `f.collection_select`. This way after the user searches for something using the drop down, that option is preselected on the following page:

```
<%= form.collection_select :vendor_id_eq, Vendor.all, :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
```